# Recommendations on writing sensor data on iOS device

Tags: ios, core-data

I need to store plenty of data points (timeseries) coming from a sensor reach device (SensorTag)

- Is there any recommended framework to store plenty of fast streaming data?
- What type of local storage system do you recommend, sql, file, else?

**Details**
   - Data comes in at 25hz per second
   - Each row might have 70 bytes worth of data
   - It's a continuous capture for 12 hours straight

Comment: Can you quantify this a bit more?   How many bytes per second do you want to store and for how long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did something similar with a BTLE device, I used Core Data with one new managed object instance per reading. To avoid excessive Core Data work, I didn't save changes after every new instance-- I'd save at intervals, after 100 new unsaved readings were available.

You might need to tune the save interval, depending on details like how much data the new entries actually have, what else is happening in your app at the time, and what device(s) you support. In my case I was updating an OpenGL view to show a 3D visualization of the data in real time.

Whatever you choose, make sure it lets you get the readings out of memory quickly. 25Hz * 70 bytes * 12 hours is a little over 75Mb. You don't want that all in RAM if you can avoid it.